# QImage is not passing through signal-slots Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am building an application which gets the image from an IP camera using OpenCV in one thread, then after processing it converts the `Mat` to `QImage`, then emits the `QImage` to the signal, and then the image will be received in the GUI thread by the corresponding slots.

signal declares in the processing image thread class:

```
void sendImage(const QImage &frame);
```

slot declares in the GUI thread class:

```
void onGetImage(const QImage &img);
```

but after that when I show the image on `QLabel` or saving the image to the disk, the program crashes.

I am a little new to `C++`, so is there any problem with the passing reference of the `QImage` object? If yes, then what is the correct way to pass **Objects** between threads without any copying (reallocating memory) overhead? Because I want to prevent even a small overhead in a long time running application.

**Update:** Sometimes run for some while, and then crashes, sometimes it crashes even in the first frame.

Thanks!

**Code: which process the image**

```
class ImageProcess
{
public:
    ImageProcess(std::function<void(cv::Mat&)> imgCallback):imgCallback(imgCallback){}
public:
    void start()
    {
        while(start) // loop till start become false
        {
            videpCapture.read(frame);
            // .... some process on image
            imgCallback(frame)
        }
    }
private:
    cv::Mat frame;
    std::function<void(cv::Mat&)> imgCallback;
};
```

**code: which communicate between image process unit and the GUI**

```
class WorkerThread: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WorkerThread()
    {
         imgProcess = new ImageProcess(std::bind(.....)); // bind the callback
    }

public slots:
    void onStart()
    {
        if(imProcessThread != nullptr)
        {
            imgProcess.start = false; // stop if running
            imProcessThread->quit(); // quit the thread
            imProcessThread->wait(); // wait to finish
            delete imProcessThread; // delete the pointer
        }
        imProcessThread = new ImageProcessThread(imgProcess); // create
        imProcessThread->start(); // start thread
    }
signals:
    void sendMessage(const QString& msg, const int& code);
private:
    ImageProcess *imgProcess;
    void frameCallback(const cv::Mat& frame); // frame callback
    {
        emit sendImage(matToQImage(frame)); // send the image to UI
    }
    // Mat to QImage converter
    QImage matToQImage(const cv::Mat &mat)
    {
        cv::Mat rgbMat;
        if(mat.channels() == 1) { // if grayscale image
            return QImage((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, (int)mat.step, 
    QImage::Format_Indexed8);// declare and return a QImage
        } else if(mat.channels() == 3) { // if 3 channel color image
            cv::cvtColor(mat, rgbMat, CV_BGR2RGB); // invert BGR to RGB
            return QImage((uchar*)rgbMat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, 
    (int)mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);// declare and return a QImage
        }
        return QImage();
    }
    // image process thread
    class ImageProcessThread : public QThread
    {
    public:
        ImageProcessThread(ImageProcess *ip) : ip(ip){}
    protected:
        void run()
        {
            ip->start();
        }
    private:
        ImageProcess *ip;
    } *imProcessThread = nullptr;
};
```

**code: UI**

```
class Camera : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Camera(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        wt = new WorkerThread;
        thread = new QThread;
        //conncet the signal-slots
        connect(wt, &WorkerThread::sendImage, this, &Camera::onGetImage);
        connect(ui->btStart, &QPushButton::clicked, wt, &WorkerThread::start);
    }
private slots:
    void onGetImage(const QImage &img)
    {
        // set the image to QLabel
    }
private:
    WorkerThread *wt;
    QThread *thread;
};
wt.moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
```

**So what can be a goog design for this purpose?**

Comment: I assume that you're returning a reference to a temporary based on how you crash when running your code, though it's hard to know without seeing your code. Can you provide more of your implementation?

Comment: Provide a more complete example. Are you returning a temporary or possibly dereferencing a null pointer?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, verifiable, complete example? Can you possible build in debug mode and post the gdb trace if not?

Comment: Hmmm, OK. I will update the question. The code is long so I will post the most important part.

Comment: Try to isolate the core functionality and update the question. If you comment when it's updated, I can take a look.

Comment: try pass QImage in signal/slot by value. Copy will be created, but it will be safely delivered to slot thread.

Comment: Wow... code updated, it was not an easy job to get out the core of code, almost the logic is something like the last updated code. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @AndrewKashpur I don't believe that is actually true... QImage actually is a reference counted wrapper around QImagePrivate, using Qt's Q/D pointers. It only duplicates the image if the image is currently active or locked, otherwise, it just increases the D pointer's reference.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh so why it is going crash, the program cannot run for 10 minutes sometimes in the start it will crash, the problem is just with QImage which if I do not do anything with QImage in UI part, then it will not crash.

Comment: @AndrewKashpur Passing by value may occur a lot of copying overhead. Because it passes through many functions. So it is not a good design, we must prevent extra copying overhead problem.

Comment: When you run your application under a debugger what's the call stack at the point of the crash?

Comment: Don't assume it *may* be slow. Make it work first, optimize then if needed.

Comment: @juzzlin I have tried with pass by value, but it again crashed after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I'm guessing but, your implementation of `matToQImage` looks slightly suspect.  You have...

```
QImage matToQImage (const cv::Mat &mat)
{
  cv::Mat rgbMat;
  if (mat.channels() == 1) {
    return QImage((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, (int)mat.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
  } else if (mat.channels() == 3) {
    cv::cvtColor(mat, rgbMat, CV_BGR2RGB);
    return QImage((uchar*)rgbMat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, (int)mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
  }
  return QImage();
}
```

But, from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-5), the `QImage` constructor you're using to convert from `cv::Mat`...

> Constructs an image with the given width, height and format, that uses
>   an existing memory buffer, data. The width and height must be
>   specified in pixels. bytesPerLine specifies the number of bytes per
>   line (stride).
>
> **The buffer must remain valid throughout the life of the QImage and all
>   copies that have not been modified or otherwise detached from the
>   original buffer** [*my emphasis*]. The image does not delete the buffer at destruction.
>   You can provide a function pointer cleanupFunction along with an extra
>   pointer cleanupInfo that will be called when the last copy is
>   destroyed.

So the `QImage` returned is probably referencing a dangling pointer after the `cv::Mat` destructor has been invoked.

If that is the problem then the easiest solution would be to make a [deep copy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy) of the `QImage` and return that...

```
QImage matToQImage (const cv::Mat &mat)
{
  cv::Mat rgbMat;
  if (mat.channels() == 1) {
    return QImage((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, (int)mat.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8).copy();
  } else if (mat.channels() == 3) {
    cv::cvtColor(mat, rgbMat, CV_BGR2RGB);
    return QImage((uchar*)rgbMat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, (int)mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).copy();
  }
  return QImage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was just with sharing data between cv::Mat and QImage.

Answer (score 0):

By the accepting **@G.M.**'s answer, I want to add some more details what I have discovered in this problem to help anyone other may have the same question.

The problem was when converting `cv::Mat` to `QImage`, the image data was not copied to the QImage, so `cv:Mat` and `QImage` was sharing the same data. After because there are two threads running simultaneously, then when the QImage has been created then when it was sending to the `UI` thread, at this time, the processing image thread (background worker thread) has already cleaned up the previous data for the next frame before the `UI` thread has finished the refreshing image job. So the program has crashed.